# Unsupported locale setting only at Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I just have pushed my project to heroku and suddenly I am getting the following error:

```
/profile/list/48
unsupported locale setting
Error during template rendering
In template /app/Clientes/templates/Clientes/base.html, error at line 0
```

The thing is that I am running this project without any problems localy and in Heroku the error appears in a detail view.

I do not think that the problem is located in any of my files, but if requested I can post it here.

Comment: Do you try to set the locale anywhere in your project? Possibly directly via [Python's `locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) or indirectly via Django's [internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/) features?

Comment: Yes, I found it inside my filter file, where I was converting a number to Brazilian standards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`heroku-buildpack-locale`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale) says

> In order to reduce the stack image size, the heroku 16 stack doesn't include language packs by default.
> You may still want to use a custom language pack though.

You can add the `heroku-buildpack-locale` buildpack by running

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale
```

Then create a new `.locales` file in the root of your repository containing

```
pt_BR.UTF-8
```

commit it and push to Heroku. This should let you use the locale.

Answer (score 0):

After I had the following code inside my filter file:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
```

The solution is given by Chris in this post.